how to receive a IMFTransform stream from the position offset the header?

I know I can get the source of camera and send it to B.
and what I get maybe NV12 .for smaller size of the packet I will Transform it to h264 with IMFTransform
what I want to ask is that if now B1 want to receive the data how he should do?
in the middle of the H264 stream he can not transform it to NV12 again without the first frame right?

"...Get the source of camera and send it to B." Why not simply send the NV12 data to both B and B1 in your "sending" function? Also not clear what is B and B1 in this question, are they byte arrays?

I want to transform NV12 to H264 then send it to B and B1 so the data size will be small. right? If I am sending to B(h264) then B1 attend and I will send h264 to B1 but I have to create another IMFTransform to convert NV12 to h264

Make sure IMFTransform is returning output to your app, and you store output into a variable. Send the variable (of h264 output) to B and even B1 as needed.

but I need start another IMFTransform to B1? since there is no the first or the current full frame. so I can not get what I need to send to B1

Are you familiar with h264 to know what is SPS and PPS? Do you know how to find a keyframe in your h264 output data? The way MPEG works is that it first expects metadata (SPS/PPS) and then, sent next is a keyframe, then you can feed or send any other type of frame data... Try as: (1) Store SPS and PPS in one variable (2) Create a variable to hold keyframe bytes (you will keep updating or over-writing this same var with data from any newest returned keyframe). When B1 attends you then send SPS_and_PPS_data then send keyframe_data followed by any newest frame data you get from IMFtransform.

keyframe_data will be updated manually? by sps and pps? but how to do it?

@VC.One how to get the keyframe_data?
